# How to annotate arguments so that list members are of the same type?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to pass a list of members of the same data type to a function. To check if the list contains members of the same type, I use a typing module. But the IDE only warns me if there is no member of a certain type in the list, and doesn't warn me if at least one member is of a certain type. How to make IDE warn if at least one member of a list does not match the required type? I am forced to work with Python 2.7 and PyCharm IDE.

```
from typing import List


def f(a,  # type: List[int]
      ):
    return a


f([""])  # Pycharm warnning: Expected type'List[int]', got 'List[str]' instead
f([1, ""])  # Pycharm do not warnning
```

I read in the documentation that to annotate arguments it is preferred to use an abstract collection type such as `Sequence` . And i tried `Sequence[int]`, but result is same as with `List[int]`. With `Tuple[int]` everything works as I expected, probably because "tuple" is immutable, but my function needs exactly `list`.

Comment: You should seriously consider taking the time to make your application Python 3.x compatible, as it is the currently supported version.

Comment: @ndc85430: i write addins for programm, who supports only Python 2.7

Comment: Is there even any way to customize the IDE to change this behavior?

Answer (score -1):

For the library `typing` import of `List`, I think the annotation `a: List[int]` does not help you to check whether your list is integer. When python was run it will get ignored.

However you could use `mypy` library to do type checking if you want to use the List[int] annotation to determine.

For an alternative of not using `mypy`, I have created the code below for your reference:

```
def f(a):
    '''Checking the type of objects in list

    for statement will help to check the type
    of each object in the list and "list_is_int"
    will update the status
    '''
    list_is_int = None
    
    for x in a:
        
        if type(x) is int:
            list_is_int = True
        else:
            list_is_int = False    
            print("Pycharm warnning: Expected type'List[int]', got 'List[str]' instead")
            break
    
    if list_is_int == True:
        print("The list is all integer.")
    elif list_is_int ==  None:
        print("List is empty.")

f([1,2,3])  # Will output: The list is all integer
f(["1", "2", "3", 1])  # Pycharm warnning: Expected type'List[int]', got 'List[str]' instead

''' Further Testing '''
f([1,2,3])
f(["1", 2, "3"])
f([1, "2", "3"])
f([])
```

You may change line 17 `print("# Pycharm warnning: Expected type'List[int]', got 'List[str]' instead")` to `raise TypeError("Only integer allowed")`.

See what it does and good luck!

Comment: You need to fix your code because `list_is_int` keeps the last member type, for example `["a", "b", "c", 1]` will be a mark as list that contains only integers. I will inquire about `mypy`!

Comment: Hey man thank you for pointing that out! I have changed it and do further testing, it can now detect for empty list as well. All the best.